# zod-prisma keeps getting stuck at the generation step

Tags: prisma, zod

I just installed `zod-prisma` to try it out, but so far nothing is working.

I attempted to run it on two separate projects, one has a small prisma and the other has a relatively large one.

Both didn't work, and remained stuck.

I can't share the schemas unfortunately. So, any ideas what could the problem be?

I also enabled strict in tsconfig, still the same.

```
prisma                  : 3.6.0
@prisma/client          : 3.6.0
Current platform        : debian-openssl-1.1.x
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node)
Migration Engine        : migration-engine-cli dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Introspection Engine    : introspection-core dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/introspection-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Format Binary           : prisma-fmt dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Default Engines Hash    : dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727
Studio                  : 0.440.0
```

```
typescript": "^4.5.2"
```

```
"zod-prisma": "^0.5.4"
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

I also cloned the example in the repo, but it had no zod-prisma configured at all. So, I added this from README:

```
generator zod {
  provider = "zod-prisma"
  output   = "./zod"

  relationModel = true
  // relationModel         = "default" // Do not export model without relations.
  // relationModel         = false // Do not generate related model

  modelCase = "PascalCase"
  // modelCase             = "camelCase" // Output models using camel case (ex. userModel, postModel)

  modelSuffix = "Model"

  // useDecimalJs          = false // (default) represent the prisma Decimal type using as a JS number
  useDecimalJs = true

  imports = null

  // https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-json-fields#filtering-by-null-values
  prismaJsonNullability = true
  // prismaJsonNullability = false // allows null assignment to optional JSON fields
}
```

but it also got stuck when I ran `npx prisma generate`

I use node v14.19.1

I upgraded to latest prisma version:

```
prisma                  : 3.13.0
@prisma/client          : 3.13.0
Current platform        : debian-openssl-1.1.x
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine efdf9b1183dddfd4258cd181a72125755215ab7b (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node)
Migration Engine        : migration-engine-cli efdf9b1183dddfd4258cd181a72125755215ab7b (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Introspection Engine    : introspection-core efdf9b1183dddfd4258cd181a72125755215ab7b (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/introspection-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Format Binary           : prisma-fmt efdf9b1183dddfd4258cd181a72125755215ab7b (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Default Engines Hash    : efdf9b1183dddfd4258cd181a72125755215ab7b
Studio                  : 0.459.0
```

Still same issue!

On a side note, I would appreciate it if someone with a rep of 1500 or higher could add the `zod-prisma` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing dependency, simply install zod.

Though, the generator should have displayed a warning.

I also submitted a PR to fix this issue for good!